# How to create stylish OutlineInput in material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
 <FormControl variant="outlined" className="MuiOutlinedInput-root">
     <OutlinedInput
     id="pdf-file"
     type="file"
     accept=".pdf"
     inputProps={{ multiple: false }}
     onChange={handleCoverPageChange}
     className="MuiOutlinedInput-input"
     />
</FormControl>
```

The above code is to take pdf as input. The image is the output of that.[Pdf input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aYU6.png) I need to style like this [Required input type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfcxT.jpg). How can I get this kind of pdf upload component in react?
Please give me a code that can be done using react and the language that I am using is javascript.